# Hive: How to create a table in Hive from a .DAT file located in HDFS without knowing the SCHEMA of the .dat file?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a .DAT file with over 140 columns. I want to create a table in HIVE and import that .DAT file's data into that table? 
How do I read the schema of that .DAT file? File is located in HDFS in my cloudera VM.

Is there any way to import that data file into hdfs without providing schema of the table?

Comment: how data looks in **dat** file?  could you paste few columns?

Comment: You can put the data in HDFS without a schema just fine. Hive, however requires a schema or at least a defined regex pattern

Answer (score 0):

Does the .dat file have column headers? If not, you can run simple script that counts columns in file (this assumes comma delimited file but can change the F to other delimiters )

```
#hdfs
numcols=$( hadoop fs -cat my.DAT | awk -F"," '{ print NF }' | sort | uniq | sort -n -r | head -1 )
#local
    #numcols=$(awk -F"," '{ print NF }' my.DAT | sort | uniq | sort -n -r | head -1 )
    echo "create external table mydat(col1 STRING" > myddl.sql
    for (( i = 2; i <= $numcols; i++ )) 
    do 
           echo ",col${i} STRING" >> myddl.sql
    done
    echo ") output location xyz;" >> myddl.sql
```